# Sticky notes in Ubuntu 17.04 disappear after a shutdown

Tags: gnome, notes, gnome-flashback

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04 and have the Gnome Flashback installed. I very much like sticky notes and they are very useful in everyday tasks for me.
I would take matters into my hands but my knowledge is very poor about linux as I have been using it since December 2016.

I can't even find where in the hard drive is this applet located to investigate something about the issue.

Comment: Please report bug - https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=gnome-applets.

Answer (score 0):

It is bug in gnome-applets, sticky notes does not create required directory if that does not exists. Try to create `~/.config/gnome-applets` manually.

Comment: It solved the issue. But now I can't delete a note unless I clear the text out from it.

Comment: That is also bug, fixed upstream. Now open bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-applets/+filebug) if you want that this fix is added to 17.04. It would be nice if you would use [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates#SRU_Bug_Template) template for bug.